# After pre-cache content with service worker, css is loaded via disk cache instead of service worker cache

Tags: css, caching, service-worker

I use a Service Worker to create a cache in the browser. This works great. But when i look in Developer Tools of Chromium, i can see, that only binary content like images and JavaScript files are loaded from "memory cache". CSS files are loaded from "disk cache". If i inspect the Application tab, i can see that all the images are in the Service Worker cache, the JavaScript files are also there and the css files also. I have no idea, why only the css files are not loaded from the Service Worker cache. I assume that "memory cache" is the Service Worker cache and "disk cache" is the standard browser cache.

Also when i load the content via fetch events, the css files are loaded to the Service Worker cache, but loaded every time either from network or disk cache.

Comment: Am waiting for the answer ?